# 403 error when trying to create a shareable URL for a folder

Tags: java, dropbox

I have a method that handles requests from users to generate a shareable URL for their files

```
private void shareFile(String path) throws DbxException {         
    String link = client.createShareableUrl(path);
    System.out.println(link);
}
```

However, during my tests, it fails the case where a path to a folder is provided with the following exception:

`com.dropbox.core.DbxException$BadResponseCode: unexpected HTTP status code: 403: {"error": "App is not allowed to share folders."}`

How can I generate shareable links to folders?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with permissions. Are you sure that you set the right permissions when you were creating your app?

Comment: @Pateman they didn't ask for much: what services I wanted access to, control over existing files, and supported file types. I just chose the ones that maximized permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you used "File type" permissions. Those permissions only give your app access to certain file types. If your app could create a share link for a folder, it could potentially gain access to files outside its allowed file types, so that functionality is disabled.

Use App folder or Full Dropbox permissions if you want to create share links for folders.

Comment: That makes sense. I deleted my app and re-created it with full dropbox permissions and now I can create shareable links for folders!